# Backbone cannot remove item from collection

Tags: collections, backbone.js, undefined

I've written the following and for some reason when I try to remove the item from the collection it's returning undefined for the item in the `removeItem` function:

```
Todos = (function(){

//////////////////////////
// 
//  MODEL
// 
//////////////////////////

var TodoModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: {
        id: null,
        item: null
    }

});

//////////////////////////
// 
//  COLLECTION
// 
//////////////////////////

var TodoCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: TodoModel

});

//////////////////////////
// 
//  VIEW
// 
//////////////////////////

var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $('#todos'),

    itemField: $('#new-item'),

    initialize: function(){
        this.el = $(this.el);
    },

    events: {
        'submit form': 'addItem',
        'click .remove-item': 'removeItem',
        // Debug
        'click #print-collection': 'printCollection'
    },

    template: $('#item-template').html(),

    render: function(item) {
        var templ = _.template(this.template);
        var id = _.uniqueId('todo_');
        this.el.children('ul').append(templ({id: id,item: item}));
    },

    addItem: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        item = this.itemField.val();
        // Call render
        this.render(item);
        // Clear field
        this.itemField
            .val('')
            .focus();
        // Add to collection
        var newItem = new TodoModel({
            item: item
        });
        this.collection.add(newItem);
    },

    removeItem: function(e) {
        var thisid = this.$(e.currentTarget).parent('li').data("id");
        var thisitem = this.collection.get(thisid);
        thisitem.remove();
        // Remove from DOM
        $(e.target).parent('li')
            .fadeOut(300,function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
    },

    printCollection: function(){
        this.collection.each(function(item) {
            console.log(item.get('item'));
        });
    }

});

//////////////////////////
// 
//  SELF
// 
//////////////////////////

self = {};
self.start = function(){
    new TodoView({collection: new TodoCollection()});
};
return self;

});
```

Comment: What does your template look like? Are you sure `thisid` is what you expect it to be? Usually you `model.destroy()` not `model.remove()` so `thisitem.remove();` is a bit suspect. A functional example on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com would be helpful.

Comment: @muistooshort - Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nYpqe/2/. It seems like I'm not able to grab the model at all. I've tried just a click event to alert the contents and even that won't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Models don't have `remove` methods (unless you've added one yourself) so this doesn't work:

```
var thisitem = this.collection.get(thisid);
thisitem.remove(); // <------ this goes boom!
```

Models do have [`destroy`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-destroy) methods though so you could:

```
thisitem.destroy();
```

That will tell the server that the model is gone and the `"destroy"` event that it triggers will notify the collection that the model is gone. If you don't want to talk to the server then you can tell the collection to [`remove`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-remove) the model:

```
this.collection.remove(thisitem);
```

That will remove it from the collection without bothering the server.

Switching to `this.collection.remove` works: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/8chHf/

---

While I'm here, you have a hidden problem right here:

```
self = {};
```

You're assigning to the global `self` (which is actually a [standard property of `window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.self)) when you probably want to assigning to a local variable called `self`. Just this would be sufficient:

```
return {
    start: function() {
        new TodoView({collection: new TodoCollection()});
    }
};
```

or you could do it like this if you prefer:

```
var self = {};
self.start = function(){
    new TodoView({collection: new TodoCollection()});
};
return self;
```

I prefer using `_this` or `that` instead of `self` because of the interesting bugs that `window.self` can cause if you forget the `var` in `var self;` or if you accidentally forget to declare `self` at all. And yes, I learned this the hard way.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation (as well as your notes on the `self` thing). I knew better and it felt 'wrong', glad to get that cleared up!